# Merging two raster .Tiff files

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I have two raster .TIFF files, one with a spatial resolution of 90x90 meters (name:A) and one with spatial resolution of 30x30 meters(B). The A has a spatial extent of south east Asia whereas B is only for a small district in India. I wish to replace the raster values in A over that small district from B and keep the rest of the values of A same.
I tried using .patch, raster calculator but was not able to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This isn't really how rasters work.  If you resample the 90m to 3x3 to make it 30m, then you can mosaic in the 30m, but the resulting raster will be much larger (albeit more compressible).

Comment: You can create a virtual raster (vrt) from your two rasters without changing the resolution of any raster. The two rasters must be in the same CRS! Use gdalbuildvrt from the command line or Raster/Miscellaneous/Build Virtual Raster from the QGIS menu.